# Change toc entry style for a part of the document

Tags: table-of-contents

I have tried to look for the answer but couldn't find anything that did what I wanted to have.

In appendix, to have the A title-of-the-appendix, it has to be \chapter{title-of-the-appendix}, but then it appear as a chapter entry in toc, but I would like to have 'Appendix' in chapter style and then the different appendices in section style (without the .1).
I already has the 'Appendix' as a chapter name in the toc using \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}

The documentclass is
[12pt, a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}
And I am using hyperref.

I am using a master-sub document style, so I would like not to have to place A, B etc infront of the title for the appendices, because of the freedom to change the order of the sub-documents.

I can't provide an MWE, because I couldn't get anything close to what I want, but I hope that someone can solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is just to use `\part`s in order to separate your document in parts such as "Main Part", "Appendices" etc

Here is how:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir} 

%Simplified solution for spacing after part number from:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467235/120578
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\partnumberlinehook[1]{%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{2em}%
}
\makeatother

\title{title}
\author{Some Author}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\begin{abstract}
    Some abstract
\end{abstract}
\mainmatter
\part{Main Part}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{One section}
\section{Another Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{A section of second Chapter}
\section{Another section of second chapter}
\appendix
\part{Appendix I}
\chapter{First Appendix I Chapter}
\chapter{Second Appendix I Chapter}
\part{Appendix II}
\chapter{First Appendix II Chapter}
\chapter{Second Appendix II Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then, you could use the chapter numbers to be inside the part like

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thepart.\Alph{chapter}}
```

and also could set the chapter counter to zero at every part begin like:

```
\part{Appendix II}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{First Appendix II Chapter}
```

etc

Full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir} 

%Simplified solution for spacing after part number from:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467235/120578
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\partnumberlinehook[1]{%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{2em}%
}
\renewcommand\chapternumberlinehook[1]{%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{3em}
}
\makeatother

\title{title}
\author{Some Author}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\begin{abstract}
    Some abstract
\end{abstract}
\mainmatter
\part{Main Part}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{One section}
\section{Another Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{A section of second Chapter}
\section{Another section of second chapter}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thepart.\Alph{chapter}}
\part{Appendix I}
\chapter{First Appendix I Chapter}
\chapter{Second Appendix I Chapter}
\part{Appendix II}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{First Appendix II Chapter}
\chapter{Second Appendix II Chapter}
\end{document}
```

That gives:

[image]

But is you insist in your request, this could solve your problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir} 



\title{title}
\author{Some Author}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\begin{abstract}
    Some abstract
\end{abstract}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{One section}
\section{Another Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{A section of second Chapter}
\section{Another section of second chapter}
\clearpage

\appendix
\chapter*{Appendix I}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\section{First Section of Appendix }
\section{Second Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]